# Authentication with CakePHP 2.4 only with sha1?

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.4

I got some troubles with the authentication in CakePHP 2.4. I baked a simple App to create a login. I did everything like in the book (Auth and Tutorial). But only sha1 worked. But not sha256 or md5. After searching and testing I came to a solution where I had to change the example code in the book and now it works. But I think, this is not the proper solution.

I did the following in the AppController:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
    class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha256'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

I tested this with md5, sha1 and sha256. No problem. Login works if the passwords are hashed appropriately.

But I noticed, that adding a user **only works with sha1**, because this is the default hash.
My User Models beforeSafe function was this (from the book):

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class User extends AppModel {
  public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
          $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
              $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
          );
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I thought, that the setting in the AppController is enough, to change the SimplePasswordHasher in this area too. But as it seems, it's not enough. So I changed it to this:

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
);
```

to this

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash(
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'],
'sha256',
true
);
```

Now everything works like a charm. But my questions:

1) I'm right, that this is necessary or is my code something else wrong?

2) As I know is `$xxx->zzz` only for Controllers and `xxx::zzz()` for everywhere and, right?

3) Why do I have to say the Security hash, that it should hash the string with sha256 again, when I said that already in the AppController in general?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** As far as I know, your approach is right. Might exist a cleaner way, but I am using `bcrypt`, and the Cookbook says to do something very similar.

**2.** You can think like you said for a simple explanation. Basically `->` is the `object-operator`, to deal with objects e.g. `$this->doEverything`. And `::` is the `scope-resolution-operator` which is used to find Class static property or method. And normally you can run this everywhere, e.g., `Security::hash()`.

**3.** Take a look [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords), you should probably change your `AppController` to:

```
'passwordHasher' => array(
                'className' => 'Simple',
                'hashType' => 'sha256'
            )
```

to fit on the recomendations. Altough I've tryed this, and didn't changed the `SimplePasswordHasher` to SHA256. It is a reference that cake seems to ignore somehow. But that is the Simple hasher, intended to simple thing, so you *are* supposed to do your own approach, or one that fits better to your needs.